# SQL Server - Return SCHEMA for sysobjects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to I get the SCHEMA when doing a select on sysobjects?

I am modifing a stored procedure called **SearchObjectsForText** which returns only the Name but I would also like to include the SCHEMA.

Right now it is doing something similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM sysobjects
```

I would like to know what tables need to be joined to return the SCHEME for each 'name'.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you mean SQL Server 2005 or higher, use sys.objects instead of sysobjects:

```
SELECT  sys.objects.name, sys.schemas.name AS schema_name
FROM    sys.objects 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
```

2005 introduced schemas. up to 2000, users equaled schemas. The same query for SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT  sysusers.name AS OwnerName, sysobjects.name
FROM sysobjects
INNER JOIN sysusers ON sysobjects.uid = sysusers.uid
```

Comment: Because of the layout of the SearchObjectsForText stored procedure I ended up using this method. But I also liked "wire science" because it was much simplier.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this will *not* give the same results. For example, sysobjects will return the system catalog views while sys.objects does not

Answer (score 14):

On Sql Server 2005 (and above) you can use the sys.objects view:

```
select 
  name                    as  ObjectName,     
  schema_Name(schema_id)  as  SchemaName
from 
  sys.objects
```

In Sql Server 2000 (and below), "schema" had a different conceptual meaning. Note from MSDN:

*In earlier releases of SQL Server, databases could contain an entity called a "schema", but that entity was effectively a database user. SQL Server 2005 is the first release of SQL Server in which a schema is both a container and a namespace.*

Answer (score 4):

Could you use the [Information_Schema view(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) instead?

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name, table_schema
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

According to [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) (for SQL Server 2008 and above),

> Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of a object is to query the sys.objects catalog view.

However, it seems that they're probably referring to an issue where you have a table name and are trying to find its schema, which wouldn't work if there were multiple tables with the same name (in different schemas).  If you're querying for multiple results (not just trying to find the schema for a specific table), then it should be fine.

Comment: I wish I could but I do not want to change the existing stored procedure to much and just doing a join would be easier. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. I gave you an up-vote for it. :)

Comment: Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object?
Vow! To me this sounds like a bug that must be fixed, not like a feature that is documented in MSDN. If you agree, make sure to submit feedback on MSDN site.

Comment: @Alex I am absolutely certain that "determining the schema of an object" means, given a table name (or object id), finding out what its schema is. And yes, it is not reliable to do this with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views because the information_schema views do not expose object id and so knowing only the table name, there can be many tables by that name, under many schemas. Iff you are just enumerating the list of objects with their schemas and names, it is completely safe to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. Note that you can use system functions on object ids to return schema names as well.

Comment: @bdukes Do you have any objection to changing your answer back, given my above comment? I'm quite certain that they don't mean the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views themselves are unreliable in their schema information. That would be a strange claim indeed to make in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I would favor using the more focused "sys" views - sys.procedures instead of sys.objects. You'll need to join it with the sys.schemas view to get schema name and such.

```
select
    p.name, 
    s.name 'Schema',
    p.type_desc, p.create_date, p.modify_date
from
    sys.procedures p
inner join
    sys.schemas s ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id
```

I would start to get away from using "sysobjects" since Microsoft clearly states in Books Online that "sysobjects" is subject to removal in a future release:

*This SQL Server 2000 system table is included as a view for backward compatibility. We recommend that you use the current SQL Server system views instead. To find the equivalent system view or views, see Mapping SQL Server 2000 System Tables to SQL Server 2005 System Views. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.*

Marc

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It is a pretty big procedure but one that will have to be reviewed. It is using all the old sys views.

Answer (score 2):

Just to repeat what's already been suggested here, here's what I've used, to get a list of Tables, Stored Procedures, Views and Functions in my database:

```
SELECT schema_Name(schema_id)  as  SchemaName,
       [name],              --  Name of the Table, Stored Procedure or Function
       [type]               --  'V' for Views, 'U' for Table, 'P' for Stored Procedure, 'FN' for function
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE [type_desc] IN ( 'USER_TABLE', 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE', 'VIEW', 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION')
AND [name] NOT LIKE 'sp_%'
AND [name] NOT LIKE 'fn_%'
ORDER BY 3 DESC,        --  type first
        1 ASC,          --  then schema
        2 ASC           --  then function/table name
```

...and here's what our good friend **Northwind** would return...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 200:

```
select DISTINCT
  name            as  ObjectName,     
  USER_NAME(uid)  as  SchemaName
from 
  sysobjects
```

In earlier releases of SQL Server, databases could contain an entity called a "schema", but that entity was effectively a database user.

Answer (score 0):

Have included an option to delete all objects starting with certain prefix and optionally from certain schema.
By the way, I added extra query to get all types which are not stored on sysobjects by default.

I have uploaded entire sample script to GitHub:
[DropAll_Dnn_Objects.sql](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fomenta/scripts/master/SqlServer/Dropping/DropAll_Dnn_Objects.sql)

Part 1: Temporary Stored Procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('_temp_DropAllDnnObjects') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE _temp_DropAllDnnObjects;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE _temp_DropAllDnnObjects
    @object_prefix NVARCHAR(30),
    @schema_name sysname = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sname sysname, @name sysname, @type NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @object_type NVARCHAR(255), @sql NVARCHAR(2000), @count INT = 0

    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
        SELECT sname, [name], xtype 
        FROM (
            SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) as sname, [name], [type] as xtype
                FROM sys.objects
                WHERE [type] IN ('U', 'P', 'FN', 'IF', 'TF', 'V', 'TR')
                    AND name LIKE @object_prefix + '%'
                    AND (@schema_name IS NULL OR schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@schema_name))
            UNION ALL
            SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) as sname, [name], 'TYPE' as xtype
                FROM sys.types
                WHERE is_user_defined = 1
                    AND [name] LIKE @object_prefix + '%'
                    AND (@schema_name IS NULL OR schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@schema_name))
            ) a
        ORDER BY CASE xtype
                        WHEN 'P'    THEN 1
                        WHEN 'FN'   THEN 2
                        WHEN 'IF'   THEN 3
                        WHEN 'TF'   THEN 4
                        WHEN 'TR'   THEN 5
                        WHEN 'V'    THEN 6
                        WHEN 'U'    THEN 7
                        WHEN 'TYPE' THEN 8
                        ELSE 9
                    END, name

    OPEN curs;
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @sname, @name, @type;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @count = @count + 1
        -- Configuration point 2
        SET @object_type = CASE @type
                        WHEN 'P'    THEN 'PROCEDURE'
                        WHEN 'FN'   THEN 'FUNCTION'
                        WHEN 'IF'   THEN 'FUNCTION'
                        WHEN 'TF'   THEN 'FUNCTION'
                        WHEN 'TR'   THEN 'TRIGGER'
                        WHEN 'V'    THEN 'VIEW'
                        WHEN 'U'    THEN 'TABLE'
                        WHEN 'TYPE' THEN 'TYPE'
                    END
        SET @sql = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('DROP <TYPE> [<SCHEMA>].[<NAME>];', 
                        '<TYPE>', @object_type),
                        '<SCHEMA>', @sname),
                        '<NAME>', @name)

        BEGIN TRY  
            PRINT @sql
            EXEC(@sql)
        END TRY  
        BEGIN CATCH  
            PRINT 'ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        END CATCH  
        FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @sname, @name, @type;
    END;

    PRINT CONCAT('Objects Found: ', @Count)
    PRINT ''
    PRINT '------------------------------------------------------'
    PRINT ''

    CLOSE curs;
    DEALLOCATE curs;

    RETURN @Count
END;
GO
```

It will continue on errors (and display the error message). It will return a count of all objects found.

Part 2: Call Stored Procedure with parameters:

You can create a WHILE loop in order to run the command until no object is left (dependencies), as follows:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 1
WHILE @count > 0 EXEC @count = _temp_DropAllDnnObjects 'dnn';
SET @count = 1
WHILE @count > 0 EXEC @count = _temp_DropAllDnnObjects 'aspnet';
SET @count = 1
WHILE @count > 0 EXEC @count = _temp_DropAllDnnObjects 'vw_aspnet';
GO
```

Part 3: Finally, get rid of the procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('_temp_DropAllDnnObjects') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE _temp_DropAllDnnObjects;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a view, why not use this to populate a temporary table you can use?

This is the solution I use in stored procedures

This is the best way to get a schema dynamically and add it to the different tables within a database in order to get other information dynamically

select @sql = 'insert #tables SELECT ''[''+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+''.''+name+'']'' AS SchemaTable FROM sys.tables'

```
exec (@sql)
```

of course #tables is a dynamic table in the stored procedure