# Copy a row within the same table

Tags: sql, database

Given following SQL (MS SQL 2008):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON
GO
INSERT INTO MyTable
  SELECT * FROM MyTable
  WHERE Id = @SomeId
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF
```

This results in:
`An explicit value for the identity column in table 'MyTable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.`

Well, do I really need to define a column list? Is there no way to keep it generic? E.g. if a developer adds a column later on, this column won't make it into this routine, and it even will fail if null is not allowed...

Comment: The real question is, why would you want to create a duplicate row in the table?

Comment: @dportas Of course the PK should not be a duplicate. The main idea is to create new entries with existing data, which will be adjusted later on.

Comment: @sl3dg3, Creating duplicates where the only difference is the IDENTITY column value is just as pointless. You should anyway have another constraint on the business key columns - otherwise you are just filling your table up with redundant garbage.

Comment: Any process that is not an import of large amounts of historical data from another system is poorly designed if you need to be turning identity_insert on. Identity _insert is meant to be an administrative task only that is only done by competent dbas.  This is a very poor practice as is using select * from any production code.

Comment: @HLGEM, thx for your note. I only turned it on because I thought this was the reason for the error, but obviously it was the missing list with columns. I don't really need it if I would define the columns.

Comment: @dportas, thank you for your concern. It won't be duplicate by the end. It is simply a starting point (think of an event, which will be planed every ear and needs to be recreated therefore every ear (yes, one could argue there about bad design, but as often it is a historical thing)).

Comment: So change the date when you reinsert it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, there is actually a more generic way, this works well without knowing the columns:

```
DECLARE @Tablename NVARCHAR(255) = 'MyTable'
DECLARE @IdColumn NVARCHAR(255) = 'MyTableId'  -- Primarykey-Column, will be ignored
DECLARE @IdToCopyFrom VARCHAR(255) = '33'  -- Copy from this ID

DECLARE @ColName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [B].[Name]
FROM SYSOBJECTS AS [A], SYSCOLUMNS AS [B]
WHERE [A].[ID] = [B].[ID] AND A.name = @Tablename

OPEN Table_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @ColName 
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    -- Loop through all columns and link them into the Sql-string (except the PK-column)
    DECLARE @SkipComma BIT = 0
    IF (@ColName <> @IdColumn)
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @ColName
    ELSE
        SET @SkipComma = 1
    FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @ColName 
    IF (@SkipComma = 0 AND @@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ','
    END
CLOSE Table_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor 

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @Tablename + '(' + @SQL + ')' +
    ' SELECT ' + @SQL + ' FROM ' + @Tablename +
    ' WHERE ' + @IdColumn + ' = ' + @IdToCopyFrom
PRINT @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Why the heck do I get minus votes? I asked for a generic solution, and this is a generic solution... I thought it might be of common interest.

Comment: This is Fantastic! Means you can have a CopyRow function without maintaining it! Thx!

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I use this as a CopyRow function! (I'm not profiting from it)

Comment: ^^ This is most certainly of common interest

Comment: Thx for this one!
But: im trying to modify it so it take into account the schema-name as well, but cant really figure out how? Neither SYSOBJECTS or SYSCOLUMNS contains the schema name :/

Comment: @Erik Karlsson: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917431/sql-server-return-schema-for-sysobjects in order to figure out the schemas.

Answer (score 17):

I'm no MS-SQL user, but in all other databases I worked with, I've never seen a way that doesn't involve manually listing all columns but the auto incremented one.

```
insert into mytable (some, columns, but, not, the, id) 
    select some, columns, but, not, the, id from mytable where id = someid
```

Comment: -1, the OP asked for a generic solution, without defining the column list. You define all columns.

Comment: I said that it's not possible and gave the second-best solution. I'm sorry that you don't like it, but it doesn't change the fact.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need a column list
2. Why insert the same value again?

Comment: An example of inserting an almost identical row (one value changed): when our customers create a  login for a new user, they would like to copy all setting from an existing user, then let the new user change settings from there.

Answer (score 0):

A big help is to use the automatic script-creater in SQL-Manager:

In my case have over 60 columns, its a pain to write every single one of them. So, right click on the table and select:
"Script table as" -> "Select to" -> "New Query Window"

Comment: As you can see from my entry above, you won't have to define any columns at all like this.